# Xcode>Source Control>Clone feature not working

Tags: xcode, git

I want to clone an existing project from github. But "Clone" button under Source Control menu is not selectable. How can I solve this problem?

[My Code ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zEPl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode>Preferences>SourceControl enabled. Problem solved :)